# When should I fix grammar and spelling mistakes?

Tags: discussion, edits, grammatical-correction

Is it bad if I just go through the stream of questions that have been recently posted, look for grammar and spelling mistakes and fix them?

Will people get annoyed that instead of answering the questions, I'm just fixing typos (even small ones, such as `Java` not being capitalized) or making the question more understandable?

Should I do this only on questions that won't be closed only?

Note: I'm not just doing this for reputation.

Comment: Unless the post is hard to read, fixing minor grammar mistakes is just annoying the poster for no reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I commend you for fixing and improving posts, these changes would most likely get rejected as "**Too minor**":

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

Before you get to 2,000 rep your edits go into a queue for review by other members who are above that 2,000 barrier. Small changes like the capitalisation one you mentioned are of no real significance to understanding the Question/Answer itself and (in my opinion) waste reviewers' time. I would reject such edits.

If, however, the improvements make a real difference and improve how the post is read or explained whether through typo fixes, language corrections or code indentation fixes I would approve such an edit.

You should hold off on minute changes until you get over 2,000 rep and can edit without the need to use up others' time on queue reviews.

*Side-note: I also reject almost every edit that just wrap words `in backticks` as too minor. They don't do much to improve a post and almost always miss other possible fixes to be made.*

Comment: Last point: That's vandalism, not minor.

Comment: @bjb568, I'd think that's subjective. It can make words, variables and technologies stand out so as to make the post easier to read and, to me, that would be a (minor) improvement. I would use "too minor" if done correctly, with good intent and not on every second word. Otherwise, yes, vandalism.

Comment: Yeah, `I` was talking **about** `this` kind of *vandalism* that is [much](http://i.imgur.com/2D8DKt4.jpg) ***too*** `common`.

Comment: Please consider that for some people, grammar and spelling mistakes are extremely distracting.  They make it hard to concentrate on the content of the question, similar to the effect of a flickering screen or the sound of a baby crying.  For example, I find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479483/should-i-use-mono-to-develop-linux-app almost unreadable to the misuse of articles (leaving out the words "a" and "the", or including them inappropriately, which is a common among native speakers of certain non-English languages).  I would greatly appreciate if that was cleaned up.

Comment: I would echo JoelFan's point that it often is distracting and even confusing. By not making these corrections it risks the text remaining harder for non-native English speakers to understand than it might otherwise be. The "Too Minor" argument makes sense if the review process is really onerous but presumably simple changes are equally simple to wave through, and so long as they're moving the document quality/readability in the right direction why reject an improvement?

Answer (score 3):

You can fix grammar and spelling mistakes, there is one rule: if you are fixing a post, **you should fix every problem with it**. If the only thing you would do is making `java` capitalized, it will most probably be rejected as "too minor".

Comment: I went into a post on WorldBuilding to fix a spelling error ("eleviate" -> "alleviate") to see if there was anything else I could do to the post. I decided there wasn't and didn't bother. The spelling mistake still makes me twitch, but for one word it's not worth it.  But oh hells yes I'll go into a post and fix code block indentation. Even if sometimes it's just the first and last lines that were "missed" due to the four-spaces needed.