# Trivial edits only concerning language/grammar

Tags: discussion, edits

I just read [How to deal with: redeclaration of C++ built-in type ‘char16_t’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369383/how-to-deal-with-redeclaration-of-c-built-in-type-char16-t), which seems to be written by a non-native speaker of English. I guess the author's mother tongue is a language with does not use articles (Russian for example). Being a non-native speaker of English as well, I would be glad if someone corrects my questions even that would mean that the edit would only contain "a" and "the".

So my questions: Is editing grammar like that considered "constructive and substantial"?

Comment: Yes, that is a good use of editing.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251926/is-it-appropriate-to-edit-a-question-for-grammar-style-formatting?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258873/when-should-i-fix-grammar-and-spelling-mistakes?rq=1

Comment: Just search "grammar" in the search box in meta and find tons of similar/related questions

Comment: Seems my search was to specific... Sorry for reposting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, improving the grammar and spelling of a post is an *excellent* use of editing.

Make sure you address most, if not all issues with the post. Remove noise ('thank you', 'I searched long and hard', etc.) and improve formatting, while you are already editing. Make the edit count!

But if all that can be done to a post is fix the grammatical errors and polish up the spelling, then please do so!

We want posts on Stack Overflow to be of *lasting value*. Proper grammar and spelling help towards that goal.

Answer (score 7):

As a non-native English speaker I do warmly welcome all edits which turn my clumsy words into beautifully flowing sentences conveying crystallized information. That way even I may learn to use this language better. It would be quite an odd reaction to be offended by someone helping me with my stumbling and stuttering tongue. If you know what I mean and know how to say it better, go ahead!

However, the aim of this site is not to be a collection of programming-oriented English poetry. Legibility must come first. This may go down to avoiding using synonyms or complicated sentences. They may make the text more interesting to read for native speakers, but more difficult to comprehend for the rest of us.

So, both the questions and answers should be written in as simple English as practical. That way they benefit everyone. Making the language more readable may mean inserting the missing articles and prepositions into the texts of non-native users, and cleaning too complicated words and structures from the texts of literature-minded native speakers.

I tried to find if there is something like "Stack Overflow language guide", but maybe it is just embedded in the general instructions. I do not know if creating anything more complicated than the existing guidelines would be possible or reasonable, but this coin certainly has two sides.

Comment: Your English already looks pretty good.